Strange behavior of @page size css rule
I am having some issues with @page rule and using the "Save as PDF" print feature of MS Edge and Google Chrome. Here is my problem:
Background
I am having an SVG file that I am trying to convert to PDF using browsers (I can't use libraries like svg2pdf or cairosvg etc. for some reason). So, I open the file in the browser and try to print it (i.e. use the option "Save as PDF"). Since the page dimension is not A4, I specify the page dimension using @page size css property. However, even after specifying the exact length of SVG to page size and setting page margin to 0, still there are two pages in the PDF.
Strange Behavior
If I increase the width or height attribute of the svg tag and let the @page size remain to the original dimensions, I am able to use "Save as PDF" option with PDF having a single page only. I am unable to understand this behavior. I don't know whether, this is a bug with the browsers or this behavior is the correct behavior and I am having an incorrect understanding of @page rule.
Example
2 pages
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        @page {
            margin: 0px;
            size: 1152px 1599.84px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<svg width='1152' height='1599.84' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><text fill="green" stroke="None" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-miterlimit="4" transform="translate(876.02, 1207.8899999999999) scale(1, 1) skewX(0) skewY(0)" fill-rule="nonzero" paint-first="fill" font-size="60" font-weight="normal" font-family="Segoe UI Symbol" font-style="normal" line-height="1.16" text-align="left">✓</text></svg>
</body>
</html>

1 page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        @page {
            margin: 0px;
            size: 1152px 1599.84px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<svg width='1160' height='1599.84' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><text fill="green" stroke="None" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-miterlimit="4" transform="translate(876.02, 1207.8899999999999) scale(1, 1) skewX(0) skewY(0)" fill-rule="nonzero" paint-first="fill" font-size="60" font-weight="normal" font-family="Segoe UI Symbol" font-style="normal" line-height="1.16" text-align="left">✓</text></svg>
</body>
</html>


@KJ, Even if I make the svg size and page size both integers with page size (both height and width) greater by 2px, still the page doesn't print on a single page. So, if the problem was with rounding, then this approach should have worked. By the way, thanks for adding the body margin css property in the code.

I make some tests and it looks like the decimal is truncated in page size in chromium. I think the behavior is by design. Actually the page size is equal to size: 1152px 1599px, so you'll get two pages when the svg height is 1599.84. You can also refer to this similar thread: Are the decimal places in a CSS width respected?.
The reason why you increase the width or height of svg then it can print one page is that the page size is smaller than the svg, svg scaling down when print.
If you want it to print one page, you can set the page size to 1600px and make the width and height of the svg remain constant:
@page {
       margin: 0px;
       size: 1152px 1600px;
      }


Thank you so much for the answer. One thing is not clear, if I increase the size of SVG, then the SVG(s) are resized, since the SVGs are bigger in size. Shouldn't the SVG also resize if I don't increase SVG width as the page size will then be 1152 x 1599 which would be smaller than the SVG dimensions?

My guess is that height and width are different. The print orientation is portrait, so if the svg height is bigger than page size, it will generate two pages automatically. If the svg width is bigger than page size, it will resize when print.
